# react-router-dom exact url to outer route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Inside the `Posts.js` component which is in the `"/home"` route, I want a link to user profile so I use this code:

```
<Link to={`profile/${users.username}`}>
```

I want this link to go to `"/profile/:username"`, but instead it goes to `"/home/profile/:username"`.

How to fix that?

Comment: You should try and make the URL a bit absolute. Try `/profile/${users.username}`

Comment: thanks, it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are using `react-router-dom` v6, which can use relative links as well as absolute links. The difference between the two is a leading `"/"` character. Paths starting with `"/"` are absolute paths, and without will navigate relative to the current location. For example, if the current path is `"/home"` and you push a navigation to `"profile/123"` then the result is that you navigate to `"/home/profile/123"`.

You can read a bit more about [Relative Links](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview#relative-links). Relative links are useful when building nested routes/links/UI.

Use an absolute path.

```
<Link to={`/profile/${users.username}`}>
```